# React: how can i execute a function only once even if i change to another section and come back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im building a Pokemon web aplication, my details part have three sections one to see the basics, other to see the movements and the last one to see where you can catch the animal.

When i click "where to catch it?" it executes a function to get the places, then i click to other section to see moves or the basic, but the problem is when i click "where to catch it?" again executes the function again, how can i make it to just do it once?

I tried doing with memo, useCallback and useMemo but still doesn't work, im sure that im not doing it how it should be or there can be a other method

My code

Parent page
`

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { usePokemon } from '../../../hooks/usePokemon';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { PokemonAside } from './components/PokemonAside';
import { PokemonBasic } from './components/PokemonBasic';
import '../../styles/PokemonSelected.css';
import { PokemonMoves } from './components/PokemonMoves';
import { PokemonPlaces } from './components/PokemonPlaces';

export const PokemonSelected = () => {
    const { activePokemon, isLoadingPokemons } = useSelector(state => state.pokemon)
    const { startSearchingPokemon } = usePokemon();
    const { name } = useParams();
    const [ view, setView ] = useState({section: 1});

    useMemo(() => {
        startSearchingPokemon(name);
    }, [name]);

    if (activePokemon == false) {
        return <Navigate to='/'/>
    };

    const clickPlaces = useCallback(() => {
        setView({section: 3})
    }, [name]);

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {
                (isLoadingPokemons == true)
                ? <div>cargando...</div>
                : (
                    <div className='row'>
                        <PokemonAside pokemon={ activePokemon }/>
                        <div className="col-xl-8 col-lg-8">
                            <div className="pokemon-information">
                                <h3>Information</h3>
                                <hr />
                                <div className="pokemon-sections-information">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => setView({section: 1})}>Basic</button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => setView({section: 2})}>Moves</button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={ clickPlaces }>Where to catch it?</button>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                {
                                    view.section === 1 ? <PokemonBasic abilities={activePokemon.abilities} stats={activePokemon.stats}/>
                                    : view.section === 2 ? <PokemonMoves moves={activePokemon.moves}/>
                                    : view.section === 3 ? <PokemonPlaces id={activePokemon.id}/>
                                    : ''
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

`

Child Component
`

```
import { useMemo, useCallback, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import { usePokemon } from '../../../../hooks/usePokemon';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const PokemonPlaces = memo(({id}) => {
    const { placesPokemon } = useSelector(state => state.pokemon)
    const { startSearchingPlaces } = usePokemon();

    useEffect(() => {
        startSearchingPlaces(id); //this function should only execute once after executed for the first time
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>Pokemon places</div>
    )
});
```

`

I would appreciate any help

Comment: By just execute once, did you mean the `startSearchingPlaces(id)` wrapped in `useEffect` in  `PokemonPlaces` component should only run if the value of  `activePokemon.id`  changes?

Comment: wrapping inside useEffect with empty dependency will only execute on componentDidMount. Can you please try console a value inside useEffect to see if the component is unMounting

Comment: There's really no way to do it entirely within the `PokemonPlaces` component. Component's don't preserve any memory between being unmounted and re-mounted, so you can't make any logic connection there. Best would be to move the hook up into the parent and handle all the logic there, since the parent is constantly mounted even when changing views

Comment: This can be a last option - is it possible to return something from startSearchingPlaces and store the value in store, so based on the value you can execute next time.

Comment: I agree with @Jayce444 that a better approach would be handling data in the parent and use the children just for display purpose. Unless `startSearchingPlaces()` does something specific that would justify running in the `PokemonPlaces` component, of course.